# How can I run a script after phpunit tests finished

Tags: phpunit

Can I run a PHP script automatically after all PHPUnit tests are finished?

I'd like to report some non-fatal issues (i.e. correct but suboptimal test results) after all tests are finished.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can detect such sub-optimal results, PHPUnit (v9 and before) has a '[TestListener](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php)' facility, that can be extended with custom code and enabled in the phpunit.xml file. It can run code before and after tests, and for each potential result (pass/fail/errors, etc, etc).

PHPUnit 10 replaces the TestListener with a new [events](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/10.0/extending-phpunit.html#phpunit-s-event-system) system.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to call a bootstrap script for PHPUnit. Inside this file, you can use the function `register_shutdown_function`, which will be executed once when all tests are completed.

On the command line, it would look something like this:

> `phpunit --bootstrap "path/to/bootstrap.php"`

And in the bootstrap.php file, you define something like:

```
register_shutdown_function(function () {
    echo "This code was called after all tests were executed"; 
});
```